# Can't get client IP in Grails

Tags: grails, ip

I'm trying to write a simple Grails controller that will return the location of the user.

The location part works fine when I hardcore in an IP address. The trouble lies in getting the user's IP address.

Upon running the below code, I get the following error:

"No signature of method: helloworld.HelloController.getRemoteAddr() is applicable for argument types: () values: []"

The error seems to be caused by the line:

```
def ipAddress = getRemoteAddr()
```

I'm connecting through localhost:8090/helloworld/hello/index on the machine running the grails app and 192.168.0.10:8090/helloworld/hello.index on my laptop.

Rest of my code:

class HelloController {

```
def geoIpService

def index() {

    def ip = getIpAddress()
    def location = geoIpService.getLocation(ip)
    render location.countryName + " " + location.city     
}           

def getIpAddress(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request) {
    // def ipAddress = getRemoteAddr()

    def ipAddress = getRemoteAddr()

    if (ipAddress && InetAddressValidator.VALIDATOR.isValid(ipAddress)){
        log.debug("Remote IP Address ::: " + ipAddress)

        return ipAddress
    }

    ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")

    if(ipAddress && InetAddressValidator.VALIDATOR.isValid(ipAddress)) {
        log.debug("Remote IP Address ::: " + ipAddress)

        return ipAddress
    }

    ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")

    if(ipAddress && InetAddressValidator.VALIDATOR.isValid(ipAddress)) {
        log.debug("Remote IP Address ::: " + ipAddress)

        return ipAddress
    }
    return ipAddress

}

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't it be `request.getRemoteAddr()`?

Comment: @MarcB Hmmm, now I'm getting the following error: 

Cannot invoke method getRemoteAddr() on null object

It's something really simple. I'm very new to Grails and the task I'm doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current `HttpServletRequest` from any Grails controller via the built-in `request` object.  There's no need to specify this as an argument to your method, as you've done.  If you change:

```
def getIpAddress(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request) {
...
```

to:

```
def getIpAddress() {
...
```

You will then be able to use `request.getRemoteAddr()` (or simply `request.remoteAddr` with Groovy's convenient accessor syntax).